# Can't cope with packages

Tags: java, classpath

In C:\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks> I have placed

```
AbstractStack.java
ArrayStack.java
LinkedStack.java
Stack.java
StackTest.java
```

The first string of each of these files is

```
package ru.compscicenter.java.stacks;
```

My my CLASSPATH examination:

```
C:\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks>echo %CLASSPATH%
.;C:\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks
```

When I'm in the stacks directory and try to compile StackTest, I fail to do that.
What I write and what I get is here:

```
C:\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks>javac StackTest.java
StackTest.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        public static void fill(Stack<String> stack){
                                ^
  symbol:   class Stack
  location: class StackTest
StackTest.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        public static <E> void dump(Stack<E> stack){
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Stack
  location: class StackTest
StackTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        LinkedStack<String> stack = new LinkedStack<String>();
                        ^
  symbol:   class LinkedStack
  location: class StackTest
StackTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        LinkedStack<String> stack = new LinkedStack<String>();
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class LinkedStack
  location: class StackTest
StackTest.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                        ArrayStack<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>(10);
                        ^
  symbol:   class ArrayStack
  location: class StackTest
StackTest.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                        ArrayStack<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>(10);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ArrayStack
  location: class StackTest
6 errors
```

Could you help me correct this?

**Added later:**

Then I did this:

```
C:\>javac c:\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks\*.java
Note: c:\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks\ArrayStack.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

C:\>java StackTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StackTest (wrong name: ru/compscicenter/java/stacks/StackTest)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Could you help me again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While compling use something like this
Javac -d .  *.java
it will automatically create package structure and place class files in corresponding packages

Answer (score 0):

The packages are interpreted as relative to the current directory. If you are specifying

```
package ru.compscicenter.java.stacks;
```

then the `.java` and `.class` files need to be in the directory `ru\compscicenter\java\stacks\` from wherever you're running the commands. In this case, you need to run `javac` and `java` from `C:\`.

Comment: This is what I get: C:\>javac StackTest.java
javac: file not found: StackTest.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: The packages are not interpreted as relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining a root directory for your app. Placing everything directly in c:\ is really not a good idea:

```
c:\myapp
```

then create a directory for the sources (.java files):

```
c:\myapp\src
```

and another one for your classes (.class files):

```
c:\myapp\classes
```

Now, your source tree should match exactly with your package tree, so you should have your sources files under

```
c:\myapp\src\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks
```

since they're all in the package `ru.compscicenter.java.stacks`.

Place yourself at the root of your app, in `c:\myapp`. The javac compiler expects files as arguments. And you want to place the compiled .class files in `c:\myapp\classes`. So you want to use

```
javac -d classes src\ru\compscicenter\java\stacks\*.java
```

This will create a folder tree matching exactly with the package tree in c:\myapp\classes, containing the compiled .class files. The root of the tree is `c:\myapp\classes`, so that's what you need to add to the classpath to run the app. And java expects a fully qualified class name:

```
java -cp c:\myapp\classes ru.compscicenter.java.stacks.StackTest
```

or, using a relative path, since you're in c:\myapp already:

```
java -cp classes ru.compscicenter.java.stacks.StackTest
```

Comment: Well, I'm trying to follow video lectures. They are not very detailed. But I wouldn't like to create directories which were not mentioned in the course. But your suggestion helped me somehow. Please, have a look at my edits to the original post.

Comment: Read my answer. java expects a fully qualified class name: java ru.compscicenter.java.stacks.StackTest. If your course tells you to put everything in c:\, and to put the .class files in the same place as the .java files, then you should choose another course. BTW: you didn't manage to compile and run your classes with that course. Isn't it a strong indication that it's a bad one?